# Apache CXF - http-conf:conduit proxy setting

Tags: web-services, proxy, cxf

In my project i have to configure the conduit settings for web services.To communicate with the web services i  have to pass through a proxy.Since , http-conf:basicAuthSupplier it's not working due to http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/svn-commit-r1240059-cxf-trunk-rt-transports-http-src-main-resources-schemas-configuration-http-conf-d-td5453353.html does anybody knows how to configure a proxy setting?

```xml
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:authorization>
        <sec:UserName>username</sec:UserName>
        <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
    </http-conf:authorization>

    <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
                            AllowChunking="false"
                            ProxyServer=proxyIp
                            ProxyServerPort=proxyPort
                            ProxyServerType="HTTP"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

I also tried with `http-conf:proxyAuthorization`
but the same 407 proxy authentification error appears.

Does anybody knows how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication supplier has to be configured as described at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
<http-conf:client ProxyServer="proxyIP" ProxyServerPort="proxyPort" NonProxyHosts="nonProxyHost" />
<http-conf:authSupplier class="org.apache.cxf.transport.http.auth.DefaultBasicAuthSupplier"/>
<http-conf:proxyAuthorization>
    <sec:UserName>username</sec:UserName>
    <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
</http-conf:proxyAuthorization>
```

Also enable basic authentication for HTTPS tunneling using the below JVM flags. Details available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html

```
-Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
```